# relation.query().limit not working (Parse), getting only 100 objects

Tags: swift, parse-platform, parse-server, pfquery

I have User table with relations "followers" and "following". I'm trying to find all objects in "following" relation. As I know, Parse `limit` by default will return 100 objects, which is why I need to set `limit` on the number of objects to return. However, it doesn't seem to work for me, as I keep getting only 100 "followings" (there are 121 objects in the database).

Here is my code:

```
//find number of followings of user(userid)
  static func getFollowings(_ user: User, closure: @escaping ([PFObject]?, Error?) -> Void){

    //find User objects in a "following" relation
    let relation = user.relation(forKey: "following")
    relation.query().limit = 999
    relation.query().findObjectsInBackground {
      (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
      if let error = error {
        closure(nil, error)
        print(error.localizedDescription)
      } else {
        closure(objects, error)

        //objects have all Users that current user is following.
        print("---------following---------\(objects!.count)")
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: what parse-server are you using? it seems they updated that recently https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/pull/3150

Comment: @MazelTov I'm using ParseServer 2.2.23

Comment: @MazelTov in the above link, they just changed default records from 100 to 1000, in my case I specifically given `limit = 999` and it is somehow being ignored.

Comment: maybe you can try limit = 0, I would also try to update to latest parse-server and latest SDK

Comment: When you call getFollowings are you not passing in a parse user? Is there any need for fetching the user again?

Comment: @Devster101 you're right there is no need for that, I already have user!(my bad) I'll edit my question. Thanks!

Comment: @MazelTov I ended up with changing  _CloudCode.spec.js_, _ParseAPI.spec.js_, _ClassesRouter.js_ files myself on parse-server as was suggested in this pull request [link](http://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/pull/3150)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by changing files *spec/CloudCode.spec.js*, *spec/ParseAPI.spec.js*, *src/Routers/ClassesRouter.js* myself on parse-server, as was suggested in this pull request [on Github](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/pull/3150/files).

Thanks to **@MazelTov**, for the link.

I was using ParseServer 2.2.23.